# How to set date to DatePicker Control in external system using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, winapi, datepicker, ui-automation

I would like to set specific date value to the control of DatePicker embedded in external system panel.By SPy++ I can read the class name of that control is 'SysDateTimePick32'. Is there any solution for me to perform that using Excel VBA?

I have tried sevaral methods but all failed such as:

API

```
SendMessage(Handle, WM_SETTEXT, byval 0&, ByVal "2019-01-05")
```

UI_Automation

```
valuePattern = (ValuePattern)element.GetCurrentPattern(ValuePattern.Pattern);

valuePattern.SetValue("2019-01-05")
```

I tried below code,but still not work, this line always returns zeor:
    'a = SendMessage(hControl, DTM_SETSYSTEMTIME, 0, pStrBufferMemory)'

```
Public Const DTM_SETSYSTEMTIME = &H1002
Private Const PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS = &H1F0FFF
Private Const MEM_COMMIT = &H1000
Private Const PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE = &H40

Public Type SYSTEMTIME
    wYear As Integer
    wMonth As Integer
    wDayOfWeek As Integer
    wDay As Integer
    wHour As Integer
    wMinute As Integer
    wSecond As Integer
    wMilliseconds As Integer
End Type

Sub Test()
    Dim hms As SYSTEMTIME
    Dim hControl As Long
    Dim pid As Long
    Dim hProcess As Long
    Dim pStrBufferMemory As Long
    Dim a As Long
    Dim b As Long

    hms.wYear = 1982
    hms.wMonth = 10
    hms.wDay = 2

    GetWindowThreadProcessId hControl, pid

    hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, False, pid)

    pStrBufferMemory = VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, ByVal 0&, LenB(hms), MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE)

    If (WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, pStrBufferMemory, hms, LenB(hms), 0)) Then
        a = SendMessage(hControl, DTM_SETSYSTEMTIME, 0, pStrBufferMemory)
    End If

    VirtualFreeEx hProcess, pStrBufferMemory, 0, MEM_RELEASE
    CloseHandle hProcess

End sub
```

Comment: You need to use [the custom DatePicker window messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/dtm-setsystemtime).

Comment: please help to check on my revised codes above, I used 'DTM_SETSYSTEMTIME' in sendmessage,but it still does not work..

Comment: Any Idea that will help on this issue?